# How to keep the request header when Location header parameter is defined?

Tags: php, http

I have a PHP script in my server that redirects the page using `Location: $url` entry in header.

But, the request header is not being transmitted to `$url`.

I see a minimum header defined with User-Agent, Connection, etc.

Let's suppose that I customize some header parameters. I would like to transmit them after redirection.

Is it possible? I would not like to use CURL for that.

Comment: It would be good to know what you're trying to achieve (maybe there's a better way?). Generally, headers don't persist between requests and responses. Obviously you can copy them from the request and set them on the response, when server-side, but you can't control the behavior of the clients (unless you own the client).

Comment: @matb I'm trying to keep Cookie entry. I know that it is being added by Server side `setcookie` but I would like to use this Cookie on a cross-domain.

Comment: you can set cookie on *.example.com but can't set cookies cross-domain otherwise. You might want to re-phrase your question or create a new more-specific question.

Comment: @matb thanks for your reply. I will create a new one. Specially because it was marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

This would be up to your HTTP client (web browser or API client?) not your web server. The *request* headers are, hint, the responsibility of the HTTP client. Your HTTP response with the Location header is the equivalent of your server *strongly suggesting the HTTP client try again to the new location*.

If you're using cURL, you can use the `-L` param, as in the following example:

```
$ curl -L [url]
```

This tells cURL to follow redirects, and there's a good write up of its usage on [this blog post](https://stackabuse.com/follow-redirects-in-curl/).